# Uploading multiple images in codeigniter not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to upload my images array in codeigniter. The names of images are `name = standimages[]`. This is my controller

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/individual_stands/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
$config['max_size'] = '1024';
$config['max_width'] = '1920';
$config['max_height'] = '1280';
$config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
echo $this->upload_images($config, $_FILES, 'standimages');
```

And my function

```
function upload_images($config, $files, $name) {

    if (!file_exists($config['upload_path'])) {
        mkdir($config['upload_path'], 0777, true);
    }

    $filesCount = count($files[$name]['name']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++) {
        $files['userFile']['name'] = $files[$name]['name'][$i];
        $files['userFile']['type'] = $files[$name]['type'][$i];
        $files['userFile']['tmp_name'] = $files[$name]['tmp_name'][$i];
        $files['userFile']['error'] = $files[$name]['error'][$i];
        $files['userFile']['size'] = $files[$name]['size'][$i];

        pre($files);

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if ($this->upload->do_upload($files['userFile'])) {
            $fileData = $this->upload->data();
            $uploadData[$i]['file_name'] = $fileData['file_name'];
            $uploadData[$i]['created'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $uploadData[$i]['modified'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        }
    }

    if (!empty($uploadData)) {
        //Insert file information into the database
        $insert = $this->file->insert($uploadData);
        return $statusMsg = $insert ? 'Files uploaded successfully.' : 'Some problem occurred, please try again.';
    }
}
```

Any idea why my images are not being uploaded?

Comment: You need to use CI's upload or you could get the job done with PHP's move_uploaded_file() ?

Comment: Change if ($this->upload->do_upload($files['userFile'])) { }
to this
if ($this->upload->do_upload('standimages')) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must send input name to `do_upload` function:

```
 if ($this->upload->do_upload($name) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this like as it is working for me.
Set your messages according to that.

```
if(!empty($_FILES['gallery_image']['name'][0]))
        {
            $j = 0;    

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['gallery_image']['name']); $i++) 
            {
                $target_path = 'images/gallery_images/'; 

                if(!file_exists($target_path))
                {
                    mkdir($target_path);
                }

                $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
                $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['gallery_image']['name'][$i]));   
                $file_extension = end($ext); 
                $target_path = $target_path .$ext[0].'_'.time(). "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];    
                $j = $j + 1;      

                if (in_array(strtolower($file_extension), $validextensions)) 
                {   
                    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['gallery_image']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) 
                    {   

                            $insert_img_query = "INSERT INTO event_gallery (image, event_id) VALUES ('".$ext[0].'_'.time(). "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1]."','".$edited_id."')";
                            $result = mysqli_query($con,$insert_img_query);


                    }
                    else
                    {   

                        header('Location:index.php'); //Redirect your page as per your requirement.
                        exit();
                    }
                } 
                else 
                {

                    header('Location:index.php'); //Redirect your page as per your requirement.
                    exit();
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code like this:

It convert array of files in single files at a time

```
$_FILES['userFile']['name'] = $_FILES['userFiles']['name'][$i];
$_FILES['userFile']['type'] = $_FILES['userFiles']['type'][$i];
$_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['userFiles']['tmp_name'][$i];
$_FILES['userFile']['error'] = $_FILES['userFiles']['error'][$i];
$_FILES['userFile']['size'] = $_FILES['userFiles']['size'][$i];
```

And pass file name like this :

```
$this->upload->do_upload('userFile');
```

Maybe `do_upload` function can't understand data in `$files` array for moving file in folder

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

change do_upload function parameter with file input name

```
if ($this->upload->do_upload($name)) {
```